# unityをやるのに必要なファイル等をポータブルに持ち歩きたい

Tags: unity3d

家にパソコンがないのでネカフェでunityをやろうと思うんですが、unityをやるのに必要なファイル等をどうすればすべてusbに入れられますか？
いつも、すべてのファイルをusbにいれているつもりなのですが、次に立ち上げたときにまた最初の画面に戻ってしまいます。
なにかいい方法をお待ちしております。

Comment: 「最初の画面」とはどういう状態でしょうか？　プロジェクトを読み込んでもまっさらになってしまうということですか？

Comment: 質問者さんと同じ名前の方から編集提案が来ていますが、本来質問者さんであれば自由に編集ができます。もしかしてこのサイトへのアクセスもネットカフェから行われており、その際アカウントが分かれてしまっていませんか？　ふたつになってしまったアカウントを[こちらのページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)から統合し、再度編集をお試しください。また、次回以降もアカウントのID/passがあれば同じアカウントとしてログインできるはずです。

Comment: 両方とも古いですがこれらが関連の話題を扱っているでしょう。[Portable IDE](https://forum.unity.com/threads/portable-ide.679348/), [Unity3d portable installation](https://answers.unity.com/questions/19893/unity3d-portable-installation.html) 今も通用する情報かは分かりませんが。